# what does importing a package do?

Tags: python

I have a folder `mypackage` containing two files

- `__init__.py`
- `mymodule.py`

When, from another script, I write

```
import mypackage.mymodule
```

a `mypackage` variable appear in `globals()`. The `type()` of `mypackage` is `module`, and by `dir(mypackage)` I can see that i contains a `mymodule` attribute.

If, instead, I write

```
import mypackage
```

everything is the same, except that the `mypackage` variable only contains double-underscore attributes.

What does importing just a package do, and is it useful in any case? The documentation does not seem to state anything regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Packages are really mainly ways of organising modules. The module import is pretty much the same whether the module is in a package or not.

Importing a module first executes the module, then makes the names in the executed module's namespace available to the importing module - either all of them in the case of `import module` or the specified name in the case of `from module import name1, name2`.

Comment: Note that the module will only be executed once, no matter haw many other modules import it.

Comment: thanks. I realise that, however my question is about importing packages, not modules, specifically. They seem to be special module objects, it is legal to import them, however I can't see how they can be used